# как получить дату которая будет через 10 дней C#

Tags: c#, datetime

как получить дату которая будет через 10 дней C#
 К примеру есть дата 30.12.2019 надо чтобы после прибавления 10 дней выводило 09.01.2020

Comment: Метод `AddDays`?

Answer (score 1):

Работа с датой:

```
var date1 = new DateTime(2019, 12, 30);
var date2 = date1.AddDays(10);
```

[Пример в онлайн-компиляторе](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gCDJV7)

Comment: Скорее всего var date = DateTime.Now()..AddDays(10);